# Python paramiko - Connect with Linux server using public-private key pair (PuTTY)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, private-key

I'm trying to connect to a Linux server using Python's `paramiko` library. I've generated public-private key pair using PuTTYGEN (type of the key - in the Key dropdown list - 'SSH-2 RSA Key'; in the Parameters field - 'RSA'). I added the output of the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`. In order to connect to the server I need to decrypt the private key (`private_key.ppk`) with the password in the PAGEANT.

When logging manually (start Putty, double click on the saved connection) everything works well - I get connected to the server without using my password.

My Python code:

```
import paramiko
import os
from credentials import * # password file

private_key = "path\\to\\the\\private\\key.ppk"
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key, password=password)
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
c.connect(hostname = 'server_ip_address', port=port, username = username, pkey=k)
```

I get the following error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
```

I suspect that `.ppk` extension might not be handled by `paramiko`.

Comment: regenerate private key using `ssh-keygen`

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the server from a Windows machine using PuTTY. Should I generate private key on the server using `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: Your question is about connecting with Paramiko, not PuTTY.